# Как суммировать показатели по нескольким категориям в CSV файле?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, group-by

Задал [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1167336). Данные и критерии их деления на категории не изменились.

Но появился доп. вопрос по суммированию показателей по 3-м категориям.

Есть пример таблица CSV, над которой нужно совершать преобразования. Дата и время стоят в одной колонке, как `object`:

```
 Категория  1  |Категория 2|Дата_загрузки       |П_1|П_2     |
 ______________|___________|____________________|___|________|
 A1_AAA_aaa-11 |ZZZ_1_aaa_1| 07.20.2020 00:00:00|2  |3
 _____________ |___________|____________________|___|________|
 111111-111    |ZZZ_2_aaa_b| 07.20.2020 00:00:00|1  |1
 ______________|___________|____________________|___|________
 222222-222    |AAA_s_12a_2| 07.20.2020 00:00:00|1  |4
 ______________|___________|____________________|___|_________
 333333-333    |AAA_s_12a_2| 07.20.2020 00:00:00|2  |3
 ______________|___________|____________________|___|_________
 B1_BBB_bbb-11 |CCC_s_12a_2| 07.24.2020 00:00:00|0  |0
 ______________|___________|____________________|___|_________
 B1_BBB_bbb-11 |CCC_s_12a_2| 07.20.2020 00:00:00|20 |0
 ______________|___________|____________________|___|_________
 B1_BBB_bbb-11 |CCC_s_12a_2| 07.20.2020 01:00:00|20 |1
```

После преобразования хочу как результат получить новую таблицу следующего вида. Суммируются значения каждого из показателей с группировкой по:

```
Дата_загрузки,Категория 1,Категория 2
```

(она потом загружается в БД MS Sql):

```
Категория по буквам |Категория по аббревиатуре|Дата      |П_1     |П_2
____________________|_________________________|__________|________|________|
      Буквенная     |ZZZ                      |07.20.2020|2       |3
      ______________|_________________________|__________|________|________|
      Численная     |ZZZ                      |07.20.2020|1       |1
      ______________|_________________________|__________|________|________|
      Численная     |AAA                      |07.20.2020|3       |7
      ______________|_________________________|__________|________|_________
      Буквенная     |CCC                      |07.20.2020|40      |1
      ______________|_________________________|__________|________|_________
      Буквенная     |CCC                      |07.24.2020|0       |0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"c:\temp\data.csv", parse_dates=["Дата_загрузки"])
replace_map = {"Категория 1": {True: "Буквенная", False: "Численная"}}
res = (df
       .groupby([df["Категория 1"].str.contains(r"[^-\d]"), 
                 df["Категория 2"].str[:3], 
                 df["Дата_загрузки"].dt.floor("D")])
       .sum()
       .reset_index()
       .replace(replace_map))
```

---

результат:

```
In [32]: res
Out[32]:
  Категория 1 Категория 2 Дата_загрузки  П_1  П_2
0   Численная         AAA    2020-07-20    3    7
1   Численная         ZZZ    2020-07-20    1    1
2   Буквенная         CCC    2020-07-20   40    1
3   Буквенная         CCC    2020-07-24    0    0
4   Буквенная         ZZZ    2020-07-20    2    3
```